# Remove delay in updating order of recent windows of the same application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings

I'm loving that <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> allows user to switch between open recent windows of the same application, I am bothered by the fact that there is a delay in updating order of recent windows after I release both keys.

For example, I opened window A, B, C, for Chrome, in this order. Now, the order of recent windows for the application Chrome is

```
C, B, A
```

Now, when I press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, active window switch to "B". 
If I release both keys, after some unknown length of delay, the order will update to:

```
B, C, A
```

However, if I immediately press the keys again, too quickly, before the delay expires, the order didn't change, it would bring up "A", which is not what I expected. I want to bring up "C". I know I probably can do that by <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, but the order is governed by this delay, which I have not control of and no knowledge of when order is updated reliably.

What I hope is that order is updated immediately after I release both keys - remove the delay so that quickly invoke of this feature jumps between most recent two windows of the same application reliably. And of course, if I don't release <kbd>Command</kbd> key, the order doesn't change, allowing me to go further back in the history.

Is there a way to configure this delay to 0ms to achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you enabled reduce motion? it should help. Sys pref > accessibility.

Comment: There's no built in delay.  I've tested this in two scenarios - my iMac sitting idle and it maxed out with several VMs running while exporting a video.  There's absolutely no delay when idle and a small delay similar to what you describe when loaded.  What's the specs of your Mac?  What does your load look like (see Activity monitor).  You're also using Chrome which is a horrible resource hog.  Do you get the same issue in different applications?

Comment: I'm using a MacBook pro with 16GB ram. Load is light.

Comment: I tried with other apps. Same thing.

Comment: After more experiment, I think the delay is infinit, i.e., order is never updated. It seemingly just loops through windows of the same app in the same order. The order is fixed and never gets updated.